# How to replace my current regular expression without using negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression which matches on all double quotes besides those that are escaped:

i.e: [image]

The regular expression is as follows:

```
((?<![\\])")
```

How could I alter this to no longer use the negative lookbehind as it is not supported on some browsers?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

I wasn't able to get anything currently working

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code or data; instead, present both as text, in part so that readers can cut-and-paste to construct and then demonstrate proposed solutions. Please edit. Also, in your first sentence don't you mean, "...besides those that are preceded by a backslash"?

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
/\\"|(")/
```

and keep only captured matches. Being so simple, it should work with most every regex engine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3wM7x/1)

This matches what you don't want (`\\"`)--to be discarded--and captures what you do want `(")`--to be kept.

This technique has been referred to by one regex expert as [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). To get to the punch line at the link search for "(at last!)".

Comment: Except `\\"` does not escape the quote, it escapes the backslash, so basically only uneven number or backslashes should be matched, which without look behind not possible with regex

Comment: @vanown, I believe the OP mis-spoke in saying, "...besides those that are escaped". It should be, "...besides those that are preceded by a backslash". I don't know Javascript and sometimes am confused about how a single backslash is to be represented in that language. As shown at the regex101.com link (where I've selected the Javascript regex engine) my regex reads, "match a backslash followed by a double-quote or match and save to capture group 1 a double-quote". Please let me know if that regex should be written differently in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these may be a completely satisfactory solution.

This regex won't just match unescaped `"`, there's additional logic required to check if the 1st character of captured groups is `"` and adjust the match position.:

`(?:^|[^\\])(")`

[image: version 1]

This may be a better choice, but it depends on positive lookahead - which may have the same issue as negative lookbehind.

Version 1a (again requires additional logic)
`(?:^|\b)(?=[^\\])(")`

Version 2a (depends on positive lookahead)

`(?:^|\b|\\\\)(?=[^\\])(")`

[image: version 2]

Assuming you need to also handle escaped slashes followed by escaped quotes (not in the question, but ok):

Version 1a (requires the additional logic):
`(?:^|[^\\]|\\\\)(")`

Comment: FYI you forgot include slashes in your screenshots ;) Also, why would second example be better?

Comment: @TravisBritz what about them?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702929/237202), I'd like to add that you may also want to ignore escaped backslashes, and match the closing quote in this string:

`"ab\\"`

In that case, `/\\[\\"]|(")/g` is what you're after.